# How many solutions for equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 15$ have two variables equal to 1?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many solutions for equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=15$ have exactly two variables equal to 1? ($x_i \ge 1 $)

**Hint**: think about splitting 15 beans among 5 children, considering the restrictions.

Comment: So you are basically asking about $x_3+x_4+x_5=13$ ?

Comment: No, in your equation, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the variables equal to 1. But that can also happen to $x_3$, $x_4$, and $x_5$.

Comment: Ya what i meant was $x_a+x_b+x_c=13$ ... But ajotatxe's answer seems to be correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Give 1 bean to each children. There is $1$ way to do this.

Step 2: Choose two of the children and tell them to go home. There are $\binom 52=10$ ways to do this.

Step 3: Give 1 bean to each children left. There is $1$ way to do this. You have $7$ beans left.

Step 4: Distribute at will the beans. This is a bars and stars problem. There are $\binom 92=36$ ways to do this.

Result: $10\cdot 36=360$.

Comment: I have two questions: is Step 3 really necessary? As for Step 4, since three children are left, shouldn't the math be $\binom {13}{3}$ instead?

Comment: First question: I feel more confortable with problems in which you can give $0$ beans to somebody. Second question: there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ ways to put $r$ equal balls into $n$ different boxes.

Comment: You need Step 3 because you want **exactly** two kids with one bean.

Answer (score 5):

Further HINT: There are $\binom52$ ways to choose two of the children to receive one bean each. Once they’ve been chosen, you have $13$ beans to distribute amongst three children in such a way that each child receives at least $2$ beans. There are as many ways to do that as there are to distribute $10$ beans amongst $3$ children so that each child gets at least one bean.

Answer (score 2):

*Step 1:* Give 1 bean each to any two children  and send them home.[${5\choose 2}$ = 10 ways.]

*Step 2:* Give 2 beans each to the remaining 3 children. 7 beans now remain.

*Step 3:* Distribute the remaining 7 beans among 3 children any way using "stars and bars" in ${9\choose 2}$ = 36 ways

*Result:* 10*36 = 360

Comment: You want **exactly** two kids with one bean. Your system counts cases where three kids have one bean (also four kids, and so on).

Comment: My bad ! Thanks ! Corrected so as not to confuse others !

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $1$ from each variable, so the restriction is $x_i \ge 0$ and $\sum x_i = 10$. You can select the two variables getting value $0$ in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, for the other three stars-and-bars tells you there are $\binom{10 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1}$ ways of solving the equation, for a total of:

$$
\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{10 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = 660
$$

solutions.

Comment: Two variables would get 0 whereas the three ones left would get 1 or more. So the n for the stars-and-bars problem would be 10 - 3 = 7, right?